# To make sure my IP "changes" regularely

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Hostnames of free no-ip DDNS will expire every 30 days. So to avoid expiration of the domain, I found a trick to change the IP every now and then, from https://catbull.com/wiki/index.php/HOWTO:_Update_no-ip.com_DynDNS_with_ddclient.

Basically the shellscript from the site (that makes sure the IP "changes" regularely) will trick the dns server with a fake IP:

```
ddclient -ip "$TMPIP"
```

Then restore back the real one later.

But, will it really work? If not, will there be any way to make it working?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you try ZoneEdit.com, which will allow you to do DDNS and has lots of other DNS options, using your own domain, for only $1 per month, per domain.

Comment: Hostnames of free no-ip domains only expire every 30 days if there has been no activity. Just use the hostname at least once a month.

Comment: There are DDNS providers that don't expire hostnames even if no activity is detected in a long time (http://freedns.io for example)

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work to force the "update".

```
$ sudo rm -f /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache && ddclient --force
```

Comment: Please do not put what you think and untested methods as the answer. I tested it and it didn't work -- `nochg: No update required; unnecessary attempts to change to the current address are considered abusive`